# [Android]_inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails always response empty products why?

Tags: in-app-purchase

My app already publish a alpha channel version and official version. but my app always query any products, it's always empty.
I'm sure my in-app product all activated。

Why can help me? thanks

The in_app_purchase version:
in_app_purchase: 3.1.5

Flutter version: 3.10.6

What can I do for it?

I tired use in_app_purchase example replace my app package id, but the result is the same.

I also use the google play account download the release version in Google Store. but the same.